# Reverse engineer PostgreSQL database in Visio results in error

Tags: postgresql, visio

I understand that to reverse engineer a database in Visio you require a ODBC data source name. I created one using the PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) driver.

In the Visio Reverse Engineering Wizard, you can select from Microsoft SQL Server, ODBC Generic Driver, and Oracle Server. The created DSNs show only up under Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle Server; when selecting the ODBC Generic Driver, there are no Data sources. When I create one using the New button, it again shows up under both the Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle Server.

When I select the DSN from either list, I can enter the User and Password, but get the one of the following errors:

Oracle driver: Warning! You are using a Visio 'Oracle Server' driver to connect with a 'PostgreSQL' DBMS datasource. By using an incompatible driver, it is possible that the catalog information retrieved will be incomplete.

Microsoft SQL driver: Function sequence error

In both cases, I am unable to generate a diagram. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The "Setup" button next to the installed Visio drivers allows you to select the ODBC drivers to use. If **no** ODBC driver is selected, all DSNs are displayed; if specific ODBC drivers are selected, only those DSNs which use that specific driver will be displayed.

In my case, the Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle Server Visio drivers did not specify any ODBC drivers to use so all DSNs were displayed.

On the other hand, the ODBC Generic Driver had the PostgreSQL ANSI drivers selected which resulted in my DSN using the PostgreSQL Unicode driver **NOT** to be displayed. Clicking on the Setup button and adding a checkmark to the PostgreSQL Unicode drivers made the DSN available for selection and the Visio was able to reverse-engineer the database.

[Select ODBC drivers associated with "ODBC Generic Driver"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXhHK.png)